# Does github contribution graph remove the contributions specifically made to that organization when I leave the organization?

Tags: github

I got hired by a company and I was told to use my personal account for Github and I was wondering if the contribution graph will get reset as if I never joined the company once I leave the company, because I only wanted my personal account contain green blobs for my personal projects and not my work in a private organization. Is there a way to remove the contributions.

Also, will people who will join the company in the future see that I contributed to the projects in the company and see a link to my Github account?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: Please note that your Question is a little too broad, unclear and sounds somewhat like a customer service question. Can you edit and rephrase your Question to ask specifically if it's possible to hide one's contribution to a particular private repository and if so, how to do it? Please ensure that you do not invalidate the Answer given and you should tailor your rephrasing to fit the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, GitHub contribution graphs contain contributions from all commits made with your email address that end up in the default branch of a public repo.  You can also choose to enable or disable the ability to show contributions from a private repo; if you do, then users will see that your contributions were in a private repo, but not which one.

If you use a corporate email address for your work contributions, then when you leave the company, you can remove the email address, and the contributions will no longer be associated with your account.  They will still be listed with your name and the Gravatar associated with your email address, but not related to your account.

Comment: If you didn't use a corporate email address, can you still remove the link between your account and the work associated? And can I change the settings so that my contributions doesn't appear at all for me or anyone when I leave the organization?

Comment: You can control whether to show private contributions, and you can remove contributions by removing an email address, but that's it.

Comment: Can I make the private contributions I made disappear for me after I leave the company?

Comment: You can choose whether to display private contributions as a whole or not.  There's an option in the settings.  That's it.